# Max of np.array subarray

Tags: numpy, scipy

Trying to find max value in rows for emlements from 0 to j

```
samples=sps.uniform(loc=0, scale=1).rvs(size=(samples_count, size))
estimation=[[0]*300]*500
for i in range(0,500):
    for j in range(0,300):
        estimation[i][j]=(samples[i,0:j+1].max())
```

estimation looks like this

```
array([[0.81546414, 0.84746822, 0.84746822, ..., 0.98916564, 0.98916564,
        0.98916564],
       [0.81546414, 0.84746822, 0.84746822, ..., 0.98916564, 0.98916564,
        0.98916564],
       [0.81546414, 0.84746822, 0.84746822, ..., 0.98916564, 0.98916564,
        0.98916564],
       ...,
       [0.81546414, 0.84746822, 0.84746822, ..., 0.98916564, 0.98916564,
        0.98916564],
       [0.81546414, 0.84746822, 0.84746822, ..., 0.98916564, 0.98916564,
        0.98916564],
       [0.81546414, 0.84746822, 0.84746822, ..., 0.98916564, 0.98916564,
        0.98916564]])
```

All rows are the samem but, for example,

```
samples[0,:0+1].max()
0.5407804178869432
```

I want estimation[0][0] look like this one.

So, what is the reason on rows being same?

Answer (score 0):

The way you construct estimation creates 500 rows pointing to the same 300 columns. Only one row is created then pointed to 500 times.  What you see at the end is the result of the last iteration of the loop.

```
estimation=[[0]*3]*5
for i in range(0,5):
    for j in range(0,3):
        estimation[i][j]=np.random.randint(10)
    print(estimation)     

# [[5, 7, 1], [5, 7, 1], [5, 7, 1], [5, 7, 1], [5, 7, 1]] Iteration 0
# [[7, 6, 0], [7, 6, 0], [7, 6, 0], [7, 6, 0], [7, 6, 0]] Iteration 1
# [[3, 6, 2], [3, 6, 2], [3, 6, 2], [3, 6, 2], [3, 6, 2]] Iteration 2
# [[5, 8, 7], [5, 8, 7], [5, 8, 7], [5, 8, 7], [5, 8, 7]] Iteration 3
# [[2, 7, 0], [2, 7, 0], [2, 7, 0], [2, 7, 0], [2, 7, 0]] Iteration 4
```

You can use np.zeros to create the estimation (or np.empty).  You can leverage numpy's implied loops to further simplify.

```
import numpy as np
import scypi.stats as sps

samples=sps.uniform(loc=0, scale=1).rvs(size=(500, 300))
estimation= np.zeros((500, 300))
for j in range(0,300):
    estimation[i, j]=samples[i,0:j+1].max()
```

The j loop can also be hidden in numpy.

```
samples=sps.uniform(loc=0, scale=1).rvs(size=(500, 300))
estimation= np.fmax.accumulate(samples, axis=1)
```

In the last example fmax is applied cumulatively along axis 1.  This is what the j loop is doing.